# Reading FIlemaker XML with C# WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest, filemaker

I am trying to use FileMaker's XML WebPublishing feature. When I try to request a database from filemaker via Mozilla I get a user/pass request..when I enter that info the XML file loads. When I try this on IE, I get a blank result.

I then tried to use c#'s webrequest function to load the URI and I am getting a blank result when using the network credentials, when i omit the credentials I get a 401 unauthorized error (expected); I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a blank result.

Comment: Should not really make a difference. The main problem is probably some Security settings in IE. Did you try any other browser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but have you tried  inserting the credentials into the URL?

```
http://user@password:server.company.com/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=...
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a same question, how to get data from FileMaker database. I know 3 solutions:
1. FileMaker php Api. Use to create web service between database and your application
2. FileMaker XML Api. It's easier than first solution, and no need know php. 
3. Now open sourced RESTfm project that uses XML and php api's and create a simple web service to fetch data in JSON format.

Hope it will help you.